# How do I do the add-migration process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

How do I do the add-migration process?

While doing the add -migration process, I get the project not found error, I tried other solutions on the site, but I could not reach a result.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try running from the folder containing your .csproj file.

Comment: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. (for update database problem)